# In general, what is a pythonic way to write a decorator?

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator, python-decorators, functor

In general, I want to know how to write a simple decorator in python.

However, it might help to have a specific example.

Consider the following function:

```python
def pow(base:float, exp:int):
    """
         +------------------------------------------+
         |                EXAMPLES                  |
         +------------------------------------------+
         | BASE | EXPONENT |       OUTPUT           |
         +------+----------+------------------------+
         |    2 |        5 | 2^5      |          32 |
         |  2.5 |        7 | 2.5^7    | 610.3515625 |
         |   10 |        3 | 10^3     |        1000 |
         |  0.1 |        5 | 0.1^5    |     0.00001 |
         |    7 |        0 | 7^0      |           1 |
         +------+----------+----------+-------------+
    """
    base = float(base)
    # convert `exp` to string to avoid flooring, or truncating, floats
    exp  = int(str(exp))
    if exp > 0:
        return base * pow(base, exp-1)
    else: # exp == 2
        return 1
```

With the original implementation, the following function call will result in an error:

```python
raw_numbers = [0, 0]
raw_numbers[0] = input("Type a base on the command line and press enter")  
raw_numbers[1] = input("Type an exponent (power) on the command line and press enter")

numbers = [float(num.strip()) for num in raw_numbers]

# As an example, maybe numbers == [4.5, 6]

result = pow(numbers)

print(result)
```

---

Suppose that we want to decorate the `pow` function so that both of the following two calls are valid:

> 1. `result = pow(numbers)` where `numbers` is a reference to the list-object `[4.5, 6]`
> 2. `result = pow(4.5, 6)`

---

We want to use a decorator named something similair to `flatten_args`...

```python
@flatten_args
def pow(*args):
   pass
```

How do we do write such a decorator?

Also, how do we preserve the doc-string when we decorate a callable?

```python
print(pow.__doc__)
```

Comment: This decorator is, by its nature, not pythonic because you can just use the splat `*` operator instead: `pow(*numbers)`.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to write a Python decorator is as a function that returns a function.

```py
def flatten_args(func):
    '''
    Decorator to allow multi-argument functions to be called with arguments in list/tuple.
    '''
    # Helper function to implement the decorator behavior.
    def wrapped_func(*args):
        if len(args) == 1:
            return func(*args[0])
        else:
            return func(*args)
    # Make help() behave
    wrapped_func.__name__ = func.__name__
    wrapped_func.__doc__ = func.__doc__
    return wrapped_func
```

Comment: `functools.wraps` is a decorator that takes care of setting `__name__` et all for you.

Answer (score -2):

The following is an example of a decorator which is half-way pythonic or more:

```python
class print_calling_args:

    def __new__(cls, kallable):
        instance = super().__new__(cls)
        instance = functools.update_wrapper(instance, kallable)
        return instance

    def __init__(self, kallable):
        self._kallable = kallable
        self._file     = sys.stdout

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print("__init__(" + ", ".join(str(x) for x in [self, *args]) + ")", file=self._file)
        return self._kallable(*args, **kwargs)
```

Below, we decorate a `pow` function.

We could just write `10**3` for 10 raised to the third power, but this is a nice simple example of a function that we can decorate.

```python
@print_calling_args
def pow(base:float, exp:int):
    """
         +------------------------------------------+
         |                EXAMPLES                  |
         +------------------------------------------+
         | BASE | EXPONENT |       OUTPUT           |
         +------+----------+------------------------+
         |    2 |        5 | 2^5      |          32 |
         |  2.5 |        7 | 2.5^7    | 610.3515625 |
         |   10 |        3 | 10^3     |        1000 |
         |  0.1 |        5 | 0.1^5    |     0.00001 |
         |    7 |        0 | 7^0      |           1 |
         +------+----------+----------+-------------+
    """
    base = float(base)
    # convert `exp` to string to avoid flooring, or truncating, floats
    exp  = int(str(exp))
    if exp > 0:
        return base * pow(base, exp-1)
    else: # exp == 2
        return 1
```

Below, we see the decorated `pow` function being called or invoked with a few simple inputs:

```python
result1 = pow(2, 5)
result2 = pow([8.1, 0])
print("pow(2, 5)"    , " == ", result1)
print("pow([8.1, 0])", " == ", result2)
```

Note that the doc string is still transparently visible through the wrapper:

```python
print(pow.__doc__)
```

Comment: Should `@decorator` be `@print_calling_args`?

Comment: Also, I think you are making this more complicated with a class as the decorator. You should first learn how to create a function decorator.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice You are correct. `@decorator` should be `@print_calling_args` I will fix it.